# Order list by average of child elements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I currently have a list of objects with the following structure:

```
public class DataPointSet {
     public string target{ get; set; }
     public List<List<decimal>>  datapoints{ get; set; }
}
```

Everything to append to this list is working but I need to sort it based on the average of every elements first index in the `datapoints` list. I currently Linq to get the average:

```
datapoints.Select(innerList => innerList.First()).Average()
```

Is there a way to sort this list based on the average of the first element in each element of the `datapoints` list?

Sorry if this is confusing, any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `datapoints` is a collection of collections, the call to `First()` needs to be made inside a lambda that you pass to `Average`, as follows:

```
IEnumerable<DataPointSet> datapoints = ...
var ordered = datapoints
    .OrderBy(pointSet => pointSet.datapoints.Average(point => point.First()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for your datapoints and Override the compare:

```
public class DataPoint: IComparable<DataPoint>
{
    public List<decimal> points;

    [...]

    public int CompareTo(DataPoint that)
    {
        if (this.points.Average() >  that.points.Average()) return -1;
        if (this.points.Average() == that.points.Average()) return 0;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

You can then just call Sort on your list.